# postfix + opendkim: "Sender:" and "Message-Id" fields not included in signature

Tags: postfix

I got postfix and opendkim running. postfix communicates with opendkim via unix sockets. All this works as long as I don't add some special mail header fields to the list of fields that opendkim should sign.

postfix configuration:

main.cf:

```
...
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/spool/postfix/milter/opendkim

non_smtpd_milters = unix:/var/spool/postfix/milter/opendkim
...
```

In my opendkim.conf I have this entry:

```
...
AlwaysSignHeaders      To,Subject,MIME-Version,Content-Type,Sender,From,Message-Id,Date,Reply-To,List-Unsubscribe
...
```

If I send an email with the postfix sendmail command like this

```
sendmail -f myenvelopefrom@mydomain.com -i -t <<EOF
From: me@mydomain.com
Sender: postmaster@mydomain.com
To: testaccount@gmail.com
Subject: Test

Test
EOF
```

Gmail will inform me:

```
dkim=hardfail
```

Using the

```
Diagnostics true
```

entry in opendkim.conf it revealed via the "z=..." debug mail header entry that opendkim didn't include the "Message-Id" and "Sender" fields in the signature but reported the inclusion with the

```
h=From:To:Subject:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Sender:Reply-To:List-Unsubscribe;
```

mail header entry.

Digging into this I found out that when I remove the Message-Id and Sender fields from the "AlwaysSignHeaders" entry in opendkim.conf than Gmail is happy again.

Because I send mail with the sendmail command I can be certain that at least the "Sender:" field has to be available to postfix and opendkim right from the start.

So if opendkim will use all header fields that it gets than this means postfix is not giving opendkim all header fields.
I tried to verify this by switching on verbose logging for the "cleanup" and "trivial-rewrite" processes of postfix, but I have to admit that I don't see anything useful in the logs, particularly I can't extract the information which mail header fields postfix is providing to opendkim. If anyone can make use of it I can post these logs here ...

I'm running out of ideas, so I hope someone can give me some useful pointers ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out the reason (with help of the kind guys of the opendkim mailing list):

In my opendkim.conf file I had only the field

```
AlwaysSignHeaders       From,Sender,To,CC,Subject,Message-Id,Date
```

specified. It turned out that you need to add the SignHeaders field too, so now the config looks like:

```
...
SignHeaders             From,Sender,To,CC,Subject,Message-Id,Date
AlwaysSignHeaders       From,Sender,To,CC,Subject,Message-Id,Date
...
```

that's it.

**Edit:**

The folks from opendkim noted that *AlwaysSignHeaders* is deprecated, *OversignHeaders* should be used instead.

Comment: If I understood the documentation correctly, it should be always enough to specify `OversignHeaders From` without any additional headers.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks so much. I was stumped by the fact that carefully using `SignHeaders` and `OmitHeaders` wasn't enough to prevent OpenDKIM from _including_ certain headers in the `h=` value. Adding an additional `OversignHeaders=` that matches my `SignHeaders` value made it work instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to sign test message with **both** Message-ID: and Sender: headers present?

Your problem may be caused by milter getting message version *before* posstfix/MTA added the above mentioned headers (I am sure any good MTA fixes missing Message-Id: header).

http://www.elandsys.com/resources/sendmail/dkim.html :
*DKIM uses the email headers and body to generate a signature. If the  headers are rewritten or text is appended to the message body after it has been signed, the dkim verification fails.*

P.S.
IMHO opendkim should provide option to generate itself missing message-id:

---

**Added for future readers**: OpenDKIM provides options to debug "headers changed" problems: `KeepTemporaryFiles` and `TemporaryDirectory`

http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html

Comment: I increased verbosity of logging of the postfix cleanup process by editing the master.cf with `cleanup -vv`. It turned out that postfix **is** sending the header fields to opendkim.